# Conditionally implemented Angular Email Validator fires out-of-sync

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I want to validate an email address only if the address is provided. From my understanding, you do this by subscribing to the `valueChanges` function and attach validators according to the provided logic. However, when I do this the validator does not fire at the correct time. An empty string will be set as invalid but a single character will be marked as valid.

My example code, from the template:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  Email: <input formControlName="email" type="text">
</form>
```

And from the component:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    email: new FormControl()
  });

  this.formGroup.get('email').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    if (value.length > 0) {
      this.formGroup.get('email').setValidators(Validators.email);
    } else {
      this.formGroup.get('email').clearValidators();
    }
    this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
  });
}
```

You can see it in action here: https://plnkr.co/edit/5RiNDFKrTJ5iHJfVtmU5

Comment: Could it be the same issue reported here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation [AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity) says that it will update the validity of its ancestors. Calling it on the parent FormGroup does not appear to update the child email control in this case.

The solution should be to call `updateValueAndValidity` on the email control itself but when that happens it will cause `valueChanges` to receive a new value, which will result in an infinite loop. By passing the option `{emitEvent: false}` it should bypass `valueChanges` and behave as expected.

```
this.formGroup.get('email').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  if (!this.formGroup.get('email').value) {
    this.formGroup.get('email').clearValidators();
  } else {
    this.formGroup.get('email').setValidators(Validators.email);
  }
  this.formGroup.get('email').updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent: false});
});
```